# How to disallow API's execution in postman?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api

I am using node js in ,y server side and I want to disallow the API to execute in postman i.e other than browser.I guess policy may work but I am not sure how to do that.Can anyone please suggest me help.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to disallow your API for any particular client. You can reject the request based on the source IP or port, the headers including user agent, API keys or other credentials, but if your API can be accessed at all, then it can be accessed by postman or any other client using the same data.

To limit the way how people can access the data you can add API keys and user credentials, but the same user with the same API key and credentials will be able to access your API using any other software and there is no way around it.

One thing you could do would be to e.g. require some headers that are restricted for postman - see Restricted headers and cookies in the Postman documentation:

- https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests

but everyone will always be able to post any request using more flexible tools like curl that will look like any other valid request, if only the user has the right API keys and credentials, which are really the only way of how you can restrict the access to your API.

Comment: Hi rsp,what I am trying to do is ...when i trigger api from post man it should say 404 not found by using policies at each route can we check the source of api?

Comment: @MMR I don't think you've understood rsp's answer. There is no way to identify the client application (postman/browser/other) for sure; an http API is simply not designed that way. That's why you need to look into API keys and user credentials instead.